# Translating "cut the cards"

Tags: vocabulaire, jeux

In card games, there is a process known as “cut the cards“. It is done as follows:

> The dealer completes their shuffle, and then sets the cards face-down on 
>     the table near the designated player, typically the player to the dealer's 
>     right. The player cuts the deck by removing a contiguous range of cards from 
>     the deck, and places them toward himself so that the stack of cards to be
>     dealt is closest to the dealer. The simplest form of the cut is done by 
>     taking, roughly, the top one-half of the cards, and placing them on the 
>     table or a cut card. Either the player cutting or the dealer then 
>     completes the cut by placing the remaining bottom portion on top of the 
>     cards that have been cut off.

What is it called in French?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [*couper*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/couper) which is also the translation of *to cut* in most contexts.